# Dockerfile CMD not able to identify file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache curl ca-certificates unzip coreutils bash
WORKDIR /
COPY build/current/database .
COPY build/current/dist .
COPY build/current/queries .
COPY build/current/resources .
COPY build/current/storage .
COPY build/current/.env .
COPY build/current/app .
ENTRYPOINT ["./app artisan migrate"]
CMD ["./app"]
```

But it's unable to run and gives following error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./app artisan migrate": stat ./app artisan migrate: no such file or directory: unknown
```

When using following,

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache curl ca-certificates unzip coreutils bash
WORKDIR /
COPY build/current/database .
COPY build/current/dist .
COPY build/current/queries .
COPY build/current/resources .
COPY build/current/storage .
COPY build/current/.env .
COPY build/current/app .
ENTRYPOINT ./app artisan migrate
CMD ./app
```

I get error in docker logs

```
/bin/sh: line 0: ./app: not found
/bin/sh: line 0: ./app: not found
/bin/sh: line 0: ./app: not found
/bin/sh: line 0: ./app: not found
/bin/sh: line 0: ./app: not found
/bin/sh: line 0: ./app: not found
/bin/sh: line 0: ./app: not found
```

Please suggest there's in mistake in my approach and suggest some way to fix the issue

[image]

Comment: Can you show us `app` ?

Comment: app is the binary built from Golang

Comment: If your app binary isn't built under Alpine, you might get all sorts of issues because the build OS doesn't match the runtime OS.

Comment: It's built under host (Ubuntu) and trying to deploy to Docker

Comment: If it's built under Ubuntu, you'll have fewer issues if you change the base image to ubuntu too. Note that my comments don't apply if you app is a self-contained executable that doesn't rely on any external libraries.

Comment: App has dependencies on external libraries. building with GOARCH=amd64. It now finds the app application is running but it doesn't find copied JSON files.
Any suggestion for the issue?

Comment: The way you copy the files into the container alters the directory structure. See @Enigmind's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your `Dockerfile`:

1. Using `COPY <src> .` with `WORKDIR /` will copy all files into the root directory of your image which clutters the root directory and may even conflict with existing files of the base image. You should really use `WORKDIR /app` or `WORKDIR /code` or something like that.
2. The `COPY build/current/database .` directive etc. will only copy the directory *contents*, not the directory itself, i.e., the contained files get copied directly into `/` and not into a subdirectory `/database/`
   See the [`COPY` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) on this:

> If `<src>` is a directory, the entire contents of the directory are copied, including filesystem metadata.

3. As others already pointed out in the comments: if `./app` is a binary you need to make sure that all linked libraries are also available within the image.
   Instead of building the binary on the host I would recommend you to rather use [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/).
4. `ENTRYPOINT ["./app artisan migrate"]` results in an error:

> Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./app artisan migrate": stat ./app artisan migrate: no such file or directory: unknown

This is because you are using the [*exec* form of `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) where the first string in the array is the name of the executable and all following strings are the arguments. But since you only used one string `docker` is trying to execute a single file named "`./app artisan migrate`", i.e., a file with two spaces in it - which does not exist.

Instead what you should have used is

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./app", "artisan", "migrate"]

# but this works as well, see the _shell_ form of ENTRYPOINT
ENTRYPOINT ./app artisan migrate
```

5. Your use of `CMD` does not do what you seem to expect:

```
ENTRYPOINT ./app artisan migrate
CMD ./app
```

This **does not** first execute the migrations and *then* start `./app`!

Instead the provided `CMD` is added as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`, i.e., what `docker` is executing to start your container is

```bash
./app artisan migrate ./app
```

Read the documentation on [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)!

If you want to ensure that `./app artisan migrate` is always run before any provided command, you can use a custom entrypoint script. For example:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# first execute the migrations
./app artisan migrate

# then exec the command that was specified
exec "$@"
```

and use it with

```dockerfile
FROM alpine

# ...

COPY entrypoint.sh .
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ./app
```

With this by default `docker` will run `./app` after the migrations and alternatively you can specify another command on the command line:

```bash
docker run yourimage ./app othercommand
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `COPY` `build/current/database` into your docker container, you are only copying the **content** of the directory `/database`.

In you case, you are copying all the content of your directories into the root of the container. In the end, `/database` doesn't exists in the container. Same for the others

To solve your issue, you can try to `COPY` the content of `build/current` into the container.

Here is a Dockerfile you can try :

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache curl ca-certificates unzip coreutils bash

COPY build/current .
WORKDIR /

ENTRYPOINT ./app artisan migrate
CMD ./app
```

EDIT : I see you are trying to copy a build folder. A good practice is to build **while** you are creating the image. Not doing this can result in bugs due to a change of environment.
You can try something like this and see if it works :

```
FROM alpine as build #use base image of the langage you are using (like python/java o whatever)
WORKDIR /temp
COPY . .
### Create your build directory
RUN build # or other command you use to build your project

FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache curl ca-certificates unzip coreutils bash

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /temp/build /app

ENTRYPOINT ./app artisan migrate
CMD ./app
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't seem to work and generate error: ` > [app 4/4] WORKDIR /app:
------
failed to solve: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/zunp8nddv0g13x8gaxojiwtmz/merged/app: not a directory`

Comment: Here app is the binary file

Comment: Yes I understood when you posted the picture of the tree. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Got same error: app  | /bin/sh: line 0: ./app: not found

Comment: It makes sense. I've been trying to build locally and deploy to docker along with copying the files. This doesn't seem to work. I'll try your approach to build everything on Dockerfile